# Short-Circuit property C

Tags: short, circuit

According to the short-circuit property in C:0&&(anything) gives 0 and 1||(anything) gives 1.
so according to the property-**0&&5||6&&7||4&&!6**,this should give us **0**.

But when I tried to run this in a C compiler this gave **1** as the answer.

[Update: removed image link, just typed in the program as text.]

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    x=0&&5||6&&7||4&&!6;
    printf("%d",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Let me try explain what is happening, then you can follow along and find by yourself what you were missing.

Let's start with your original expression

```
0&&5||6&&7||4&&!6
```

This expression is written as a short form without any parentheses.

This is similar to standard mathematical expressions where `2*7+3*8` is understood to mean that the `*` has precedence over `+`, so this is actually a short form for `(2*7)+(3*8)`, and `2*7+3*8+4*3` is short form for `((2*7)+(3*8))+(4*3)`.

In the same way, the above C expression implicit operator precedence can be made explicit by rewriting with parentheses:

```
( (0&&5) || (6&&7) ) || (4&&!6)
```

**The above step appears to be what you are missing, and therefore you are misinterpreting the meaning of the written expression.**

We can then consider the three small parentheses separately:

- `(0 && whatever)` is `0` (short circuit applies)
- `(6 && 7)` is `1` (both 6 and 7 are non-zero i.e. true, so result is true)
- `(4 && !6)` is `nonzero && zero` is `zero` is `0` (which, as it turns out later, we do not actually need to evaluate)

So... the whole expression

```
( (0&&5) || (6&&7) ) || (4&&!6)
```

turns out to be

```
( 0 || 1 ) || does_not_matter
```

or

```
1          || does_not_matter     (short circuit applies)
```

which is `1`.

Comment: But why should go through such a process like taking precedence or evaluating the terms,according to short circuit property for 0&&(anything) shouldnt we just  directly ignore the 'anything' part and directly put 0 as answer. plz correct me if im understanding anything wrong.

Comment: The original expression assigned to `x` is not `0 && (anything)`. It is `( (0&&doesnotmatter) || (nonzero && nonzero) ) || turnsoutitdoesnotmatter`. Similar to normal arithmetic terms where you do not need to write the parentheses in `(3*7) + (2*8)`, so the expression `3*7+2*8` is the same.